# Get first word of string

Tags: javascript, split

Okay, here is my code with details of what I have tried to do:

```
var str = "Hello m|sss sss|mmm ss";
//Now I separate them by "|"
var str1 = str.split("|");

//Now I want to get the first word of every split-ed sting parts:

for (var i = 0; i < codelines.length; i++) {
  //What to do here to get the first word of every spilt
}
```

So what should I do there? :\

What I want to get is :

- `firstword[0]` will give `"Hello"`
- `firstword[1]` will give `"sss"`
- `firstword[2]` will give `"mmm"`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Split again by a whitespace:

```
var firstWords = [];
for (var i=0;i<codelines.length;i++)
{
  var words = codelines[i].split(" ");
  firstWords.push(words[0]);
}
```

Or use [String.prototype.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) (probably faster):

```
var firstWords = [];
for (var i=0;i<codelines.length;i++)
{
  var codeLine = codelines[i];
  var firstWord = codeLine.substr(0, codeLine.indexOf(" "));
  firstWords.push(firstWord);
}
```

Comment: @SasukeKun You forgot a `s` in `firstWords` after the *for* loop: http://jsbin.com/umeqi4/19/

Comment: Yes, looks like `String.prototype.substr()` is slightly faster: http://jsperf.com/get-first-word-of-string

Comment: `'hello'.split(' ')[0] === 'hello'`.  `'hello'.substr(...) === ''`

Comment: substr is now deprecated, you can use substring method instead but it fails for strings which there is only word (not having space to find by indexOf)

Comment: split is slow for long strings as it iterates to the end of string until find all occurrences of space character

Answer (score 98):

Use **regular expression**

```js
var totalWords = "foo love bar very much.";

var firstWord = totalWords.replace(/ .*/,'');

$('body').append(firstWord);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Never thought of that! It basically replaces everything it finds after the first space by an empty string. I prefer this solution due to its simplicity.

Comment: @BimalGrg , Can you explain this RegExp? and if I want to just take the first word and second character after space, like this " Bimal G" ?

Comment: @DevAS I dont know the Regex of your question but there is other simple method to do it, like javascript split method.

Comment: I mean this one `/ .*/` @BimalGrg

Comment: It means, replace all the words of given string with space after the first space occurred.

Comment: This actually doesn't work with break lines \n

Answer (score 40):

To **get first word of string** you can do this:

```js
let myStr = "Hello World"
let firstWord = myStr.split(" ")[0]
console.log(firstWord)
```

`split(" ")` will convert your string into an array of words (substrings resulted from the division of the string using space as divider) and then you can get the first word accessing the first array element with [0].

See more about the [split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 19):

I 'm using this :

```
function getFirstWord(str) {
        let spaceIndex = str.indexOf(' ');
        return spaceIndex === -1 ? str : str.substring(0, spaceIndex);
    };
```

Comment: Please update your answer with `substring` method as `substr` is deprecated [substr docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) ;)

Answer (score 7):

How about using underscorejs

```
str = "There are so many places on earth that I want to go, i just dont have time. :("
firstWord = _.first( str.split(" ") )
```

Answer (score 4):

An improvement upon previous answers (working on multi-line or tabbed strings):

```
String.prototype.firstWord = function(){return this.replace(/\s.*/,'')}
```

**Or** using [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) and [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
String.prototype.firstWord = function(){let sp=this.search(/\s/);return sp<0?this:this.substr(0,sp)}
```

**Or** *without* regex:

```
String.prototype.firstWord = function(){
  let sps=[this.indexOf(' '),this.indexOf('\u000A'),this.indexOf('\u0009')].
   filter((e)=>e!==-1);
  return sps.length? this.substr(0,Math.min(...sps)) : this;
}
```

Examples:

```js
String.prototype.firstWord = function(){return this.replace(/\s.*/,'')}
console.log(`linebreak
example 1`.firstWord()); // -> linebreak
console.log('space example 2'.firstWord()); // -> singleline
console.log('tab example 3'.firstWord()); // -> tab
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "Hello m|sss sss|mmm ss"
//Now i separate them by "|"
var str1 = str.split('|');

//Now i want to get the first word of every split-ed sting parts:

for (var i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
{
    //What to do here to get the first word :)
    var firstWord = str1[i].split(' ')[0];
    alert(firstWord);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code should get you the first word,

```
var str = "Hello m|sss sss|mmm ss"
//Now i separate them by "|"
var str1 = str.split('|');

 //Now i want to get the first word of every split-ed sting parts:

 for (var i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
 {
     //What to do here to get the first word :(
     var words = str1[i].split(" ");
     console.log(words[0]);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In modern JS, this is simplified, and you can write something like this:

```js
const firstWords = str =>
  str .split (/\|/) .map (s => s .split (/\s+/) [0])

const str = "Hello m|sss sss|mmm ss"

console .log (firstWords (str))
```

We first split the string on the `|` and then split each string in the resulting array on any white space, keeping only the first one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised this method hasn't been mentioned: `"Some string".split(' ').shift()`

---

To answer the question directly:

```
let firstWords = []
let str = "Hello m|sss sss|mmm ss";
const codeLines = str.split("|");

for (var i = 0; i < codeLines.length; i++) {
  const first = codeLines[i].split(' ').shift()
  firstWords.push(first)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const getFirstWord = string => {
    const firstWord = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
        if (string[i] === ' ') break;
        firstWord.push(string[i]);
    }
    return firstWord.join('');
};
console.log(getFirstWord('Hello World'));
```

or simplify it:

```
const getFirstWord = string => {
    const words = string.split(' ');
    return words[0];
};
console.log(getFirstWord('Hello World'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code should get you the first word,**

```
const myName = 'Jahid Bhuiyan';
console.log(myName.slice(0, myName.indexOf(' ')));
```

*Ans will be "Jahid"*