# how can i fix this, my value outputs only the first word

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set a category and a subcategory. In order to do that I have to get the selected category to be exactly as the sub category father so that I can get the subcategory from my firestore.

But when I try to get the value, my value only outputs the first word.
For example when I select `school supplies`, I only get `school` as my `value`.
This is how my `JS` code  looks like.

```
const category = document.getElementById('category');

database.collection("category").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    const categoryItem = doc.data().category;
    category.innerHTML += "<Option value="+categoryItem+">"+ categoryItem +"</Option>"
  });
});

function getComboA(selectObject) {
  var value = selectObject.value;  
  console.log(value);
}
```

And this is my `HTML`. But when I select Male it gives me the whole `value` `man male`.

```
<select id="category" onchange="getComboA(this)">
  <option value="man male">Male</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I didnt understand the achievement you try to do in rendering. Are you saying categoryItem is both "man male" and "Male"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558417/get-first-word-of-string
**Try this**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did
`"<Option value="+categoryItem+">"+ categoryItem +"</Option>"`

what it should be
`"<Option value=\""+categoryItem+"\">"+categoryItem+"</Option>"`

should put `\""+string+"\"`

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the title of your question, you wan't to get the first word of the current selected `value` from your options.

So if the selected option's value is `school supplies`, you want to get `school` or if the value is `man male` you want to get `man`.

To achieve this, you can convert the value to `array` and reference the first `element` of that array as the first word.

```js
function getComboA(selectObject) {
  const words = selectObject.value.split(" ");
  const firstWord = words[0];

  console.log(firstWord);
}
```

```html
<select id="category" onchange="getComboA(this)">
  <option value="man male">Male</option>
  <option value="school supplies">School Supplies</option>
</select>
```

Comment: no its giving me only the first word i want to get the full word